# How can i mention my self, Responsible Moderator: who muted

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, mute, mention

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        await ctx.send('Please specify a member!')
        return
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member} has been muted!",
                          description=f"Responsible Moderator: {}\nCreated by 死   死#0001", color=discord.Colour.blue())
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Read the title, idk how i mention who write the command

Comment: `ctx.message.author` is also an instance of `discord.Member` like your `member` variable. --> `f"Responsible Moderator: {ctx.message.author}"`

Comment: Thanks you are amazing